# Python 3.6.5 installed but the file taking python 2.7 as a default

Tags: python, scrapy

when i try to get default python version its showing 3.6 but when i try to run my code its running in python 2.7 ...i have used scrapy crawl cablo to make the file run
ABC abstract method is also installed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>    
sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 249, in _init_
super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in _init_
self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 336, in _get_spider_loader
return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in _init_
self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/megha/Downloads/Data_scuff/Data_scuff/spiders/cablo.py", line 11, in <module>

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
```

ImportError: cannot import name ABC

[image]

Comment: Can you please show `cablo.py` and show how you're seeing what python version you think it should be? For example, try `python3 cablo.py`

Comment: i am running in python3 only

Comment: from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import enum
import logging
import os
import re

from pyvirtualdisplay.display import Display
from selenium import webdriver

from Data_scuff import settings
from Data_scuff.utils import utils

Comment: Look into pyenv and virtualenv, they are great for managing multiple versions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the shell commands and your script

Comment: use: *#!/usr/bin/env python3* in your script

Comment: ABC works differently under python 3, you need to use six for compatibility with 2.7

Comment: @user2413548 i tried that too....still its showing same error

Comment: as suggested above: please edit the question and include the code instead of placing it in the comment

Comment: close and open your terminals or reboot system then shoe output of this command `which python`

Answer (score 0):

ABC python 3: here a snippet of code I use for both 2.7 and 3.5. You can skip the six stuf if you don't care about 2.7

```
import six
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


@six.add_metaclass(ABCMeta)
class BaseRequest(object):
    """baseclass for request classes."""

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = dict()
```

Comment: you still didn't edit your question and add the code, that leaves only guessing

Comment: I think you will need to (re)nstall scrapy with pip3 to get it available under python3

Comment: Your problem isn't python 3. The scrapy that runs seems to be installed for use by python2. Your log shows that. If you do the import using python2.7 it will fail. So installing scrapy with pip3 has a good chance. First I would remove it from the 2.7 because it install some binaries under usr/local/bin ? I don't know scrapy so check out those details